# Vuejs having increment numbers in forms

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have input field to type numbers

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" v-model="verse.number" required>
```

I'd like to increment this number after store it in database.

#### Example

I enter `1` and save my form, next time i open my form the number be `2` instead of i be needed to type it every time.

## Code

```
data() {
    return {
        verse: {
            number: '',
            heading: '',
            body: '',
            book_id: '',
            chapter_id: '',
        }
    }
},
submit: function(e) {
    axios.post('/my_url', this.verse)
    .then(res => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
        this.getVerses.push( res.data.verse );
        this.verse = {
            number: this.verse.number, // here
            heading: '',
            body: '',
            book_id: this.verse.book_id,
            chapter_id: this.verse.chapter_id,
        };
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle authentication and validation errors here
        this.errors = error.response.data.errors
        this.isLoading = false
    })
}
```

I have already tried these but none worked as i wanted,

```
this.verse = {
  number: this.verse.number +=1,
  ...
```

and

```
this.verse = {
  number: this.verse.number +1,
  ...
```

any idea?

Comment: Try this.verse.number = this.verse.number + 1; That should work. For more information about this checkout reactivity topic in VueJS doc.

Comment: it returns like this: I save `2` next time i open is `21`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this.verse.number type is String, so

```
this.verse.number + 1 // ''+ 1 = '1'
```

You should set your default value of verse.number( in `data() {}` ) to `0` insteed `''`. Just change `number: '',` to `number: 0,` And it will be

```
this.verse.number + 1 // 0 + 1 = 1
```

And next increment will `1 + 1 = 2` etc

Comment: i changed my number in data, and saved number 1, next time i opened still was `1`

Comment: ah, sorry, And on line `number: this.verse.number, // here` add +1 `number: this.verse.number + 1`,

Comment: .returning `11`

Comment: It does mean, is your this.verse.number type is String, Can you show your line now in data() ?

Comment: in data() `verse: { number: 0,`  in function `this.verse = {number: this.verse.number +1,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205478/discussion-between-andrey-kadnikov-and-mafortis).